# JPA - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, osgi, entitymanager

I have a weird problem with my Java code.

I am facing the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class

Note that I have a persistence.xml where my entites are listed.
My entites have @Entity annotation.

When I do:

```
final Query q = entityManager.createQuery("from " + className + " c");  
q.getResultList().iterator();
```

it returns me results.

But when I do:

```
// pType is Class<T> 
final TypedQuery<T> queryAll = entityManager.createQuery(query.select(query.from(pType))); 
return queryAll.getResultList();
```

it returns me the Exception above.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: What is `pType`? Is it a string that contains something like `MyClassName.class`? Make sure that the `.class` isn't in there.

Comment: As I mentioned in my snippet, "pType is Class<T> type"

Answer (score 0):

I've had a error similar your, in my persistence.xml, but  I didn't add a class entity, check if your problem is this.
Example in persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="PERSISTENCE" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>CLASSE_ENTITY</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue may occur when given class has not been added to Hibernate configuration.

One of the way to add it using

```java
new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration()
      .addProperties(properties)
      .addAnnotatedClass(MyEntity.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

check your Hibernate and Spring `versions` to be compatible. I had the same issue, I had changed the Hibernate and Spring versions, the problem has gone.